# Why VScode PlatformIO unit test can not use function declare in header file?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, platformio

VScode PlatformIO unit test can not use function declare in header file, but use the function definition code is work.
It show **undefined reference to `wifiInit()'**
[image]
**Code**

```
#include <unity.h>

#include "wifi/wifi.h"

void test_unit() {
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(EXIT_SUCCESS,wifiInit());
}

void setup() {
    delay(2000);
    UNITY_BEGIN(); 
    RUN_TEST(test_unit);
}

void loop() {}
```

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#ifndef __wifi_init_h_
#define __wifi_init_h_

#define WIFI_SSID "**"
#define WIFI_PASSWD "***"

int wifiInit();
#endif
```

```
#include "wifi/wifi.h"

int wifiInit() {
    // 设置ESP32通过WIFI连接网络
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWD);
    WiFi.config(WiFi.localIP(), WiFi.gatewayIP(), WiFi.subnetMask(), (uint32_t)0xDF050505, (uint32_t)0x72727272);
    // 打印连接状态
    Serial.println("Connecting");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.print("\nIP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
}
```

**I coyied the wifiInit() in wifi.cpp to the wifi.h, it worked.**

Comment: Sorry to ask, but have you found an answer to this? I cannot seem to find an answer elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

This is because the unit test does not build your source file by default, so at link time the linker can't find the *definition* (`.c`) of `wifiInit` (only the *declaration*, `.h`)
One way to fix this is to tell PlatformIO to build your source files when it runs unit tests: https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/section_env_test.html#test-build-src

```
[env:myenv]
platform = ...
test_build_src = yes
```

Be careful though, depending on your test environment you may not have access to platform-specific headers/libraries! i.e. on a `native` unit test build you would not be able to `#include <Arduino>` in your source files.